# Google sheets | Sending a cell range to email body

Tags: html, email, google-sheets

I currently have a script that references one cell (D28) and places it in the email body. Is it possible to reference a range of cells? I wish to send cells (D28:D40) to the email body.

Any help much appreciated.....

```
function emailPdf(){ // this is the function to call
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var shName = sh.getName()

  sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ('email@gmail.com'), sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), Utilities.formatDate(sh.getRange('B4').getValue(), "NZ", "EEE MMM dd"), sh.getRange('D28').getValue());
}
function sendSpreadsheetToPdf(sheetNumber, pdfName, email, subject, date, htmlbody) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
  var sheetId = sheetNumber ? spreadsheet.getSheets()[sheetNumber].getSheetId() : null;
  var url_base = spreadsheet.getUrl().replace(/edit$/,'');

  var url_ext = 'export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf'   // export as pdf

      + (sheetId ? ('&gid=' + sheetId) : ('&id=' + spreadsheetId)) 
      // following parameters are optional...
      + '&size=A4'      // paper size
      + '&portrait=true'    // orientation, false for landscape
      + '&fitw=true'        // fit to width, false for actual size
      + '&sheetnames=true&printtitle=false&pagenumbers=true'  // hide optional headers and footers
      + '&gridlines=false'  // hide gridlines
      + '&fzr=false';       // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page

  var options = {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
    }
  }

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_base + url_ext, options);
  var blob = response.getBlob().setName(pdfName + '.pdf');
  if (email) {
    var mailOptions = {
      attachments:blob, htmlBody:htmlbody
    }
MailApp.sendEmail(
      email, 
      subject+" | "+date+" (" + pdfName +")",
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);

MailApp.sendEmail(
      Session.getActiveUser().getEmail(), 
      subject+" | "+date+" (" + pdfName +")",
      "html content only", 
      mailOptions);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you use getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) , and then getValues() with the array?

Comment: You can also embed a table in the email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50027628/google-sheets-script-email-with-a-html-table-that-only-has-a-set-of

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried your suggestion ```sh.getRange(28,4,13,1).getValue()```, but unfortunately it only returns the first cell (D28) in the email body. I might have to give allot of thought to embed a table. It is a bit beyond me. I don't need any formatting, just the data from cells (D28:D40) with simple line breaks between the cells.

Comment: did you use getValue() or getValues() with a plural?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues

Comment: Hi there, I have tried both getVaule() and getvaules(). getValues() returns the message "Ljava.lang.Object;@7d193b9b" in the email body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a script I have that pulls multiple values and puts them into an array and emails them. Make sure after `.getValues()` you have `.toString()` to converts the value into strings which might be where you are encountering your "Ljava.lang.Object;@7d193b9b" problem. It will just produce a list with values separated by commas.

so like:

```
var list = refsheet.getRange(2, 14, 2+i).getValues().toString()
```

then for complete example:

```
    function AttendanceAlert() {
      var refsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("AttendanceNotification")
      var column = refsheet.getRange('N2:N');
      var cell = refsheet.getRange(1, 10).getValue(); //get the date I want to search for
      var celldate = new Date(cell);
      var date = Utilities.formatDate(celldate, "GMT","EEE, MM-dd-yy");
      var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
      var ct = 0;
      while ( values[ct][0] != "" ) {
        ct++;
      }
     var numbers = ct

      for(var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
      var list = refsheet.getRange(2, 14, 2+i).getValues().toString()
      Logger.log(list) 
      }
       var recipientsTO = "recipient@email.com" + "," + "recipient@email.com";
      MailApp.sendEmail(recipientsTO, "Attendance Update :"+" "+ date , "These individuals have 5 or more total infractions (see parentheses for total), and one recent infraction as of "+ date + ":" +" "+ list + '\n' +

}
```

Now for your example:

```
sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ('email@gmail.com'), sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), Utilities.formatDate(sh.getRange('B4').getValue(), "NZ", "EEE MMM dd"), sh.getRange(28,4,13,1).getValues().toString());
```

Let me know if that works.

Update:

To get the values seperated by line breaks rather than commas, try this:

```
sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ('email@gmail.com'), sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), Utilities.formatDate(sh.getRange('B4').getValue(), "NZ", "EEE MMM dd"), sh.getRange(28,4,13,1).getValues().join("\n"));
```

if that doesn't work, try:

```
sendSpreadsheetToPdf(3, shName, ('email@gmail.com'), sh.getRange('B3').getValue(), Utilities.formatDate(sh.getRange('B4').getValue(), "NZ", "EEE MMM dd"), sh.getRange(28,4,13,1).getValues().join('<br/>'));
```

Comment: Yes, that is working. Thanks heaps! Text is now populated to the email body (in a string) with a comma separating each row of the spreadsheet. Formatting this with line breaks rather than commas would require an HTML template...correct?